# Types in a function in Haskell

Tags: function, haskell, types, functional-programming

I am trying to write a function called check that when applied to n returns a Bool indicating whether the ∑r=0 to n (n choose r) = 2^n

I have made the factorial and choose functions which work but I am having difficulty understanding what the type would be for the check function. I have written what I have done for it and I think logically it might work but I am not sure. The error I get when running says 'couldn't match type a -> Bool to actual type Bool' but I am not entirely sure how to make it an actual Bool type.

```
factorial :: (Integral a) => a -> a
factorial 0 = 1 
factorial n = n * factorial (n - 1)

choose :: (Integral a) => a -> a -> a
n `choose` r
    | r < 0     = 0
    | r > n     = 0
    | otherwise = factorial n `div` (factorial r * factorial (n-r))

check :: (Integral a) => a -> a -> Bool 
check n = (if (factorial (choose n)) == 2^n then True else False)
```

Comment: 1) Fix the type: `a->a->Bool` takes two arguments, but you only need one. 2) Try a list comprehension e.g. `sum [ ... | r<-[0..n] ] == 2^n`. 3) Never use `if condition then True else False` -- it's equivalent to just `condition`, only more complex to read.

Comment: Style note: `if (factorial (choose n)) == 2^n then True else False` is equivalent to just writing: `factorial (choose n) == 2^n`

Comment: Some observations. `choose` takes two arguments, but you have given it only one in `factorial (choose n)`; perhaps this is related to the problem you are having. Where is the code reflection in `check` of `r`, and its bounds of `0` to `n`, and the summation of the results? What math is being reflected by the `factorial` in `check`?

Answer (score 2):

The correct type declaration for `check` is `a -> Bool`

The types are separated by `->` and grouped using parentheses.

The last type is the returned type, here `Bool`.

The previous types are the input types, here `a`.

Your error message is `couldn't match type a -> Bool to actual type Bool`. What's happening here is that Haskell matches the `a` to variable `n`, but is then left with `a -> Bool`, when actually the return type is `Bool`.